# Swift 2: Spawning a new sprite every 30 seconds

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Looking for a method to spawn a new sprite in the center of the screen every 30 seconds. And it has to be affected by gravity.

I have managed to spawn the sprite, but when trying to set affectedByGravity to true the game crashes.

"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

This is the code i got:

```
  self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0, target: self, selector: "spawningCars", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func spawningCars() {

    let enemyTowardsTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "player")
    let enemyTowards = SKSpriteNode(texture: enemyTowardsTexture)
    enemyTowards.position = ourCamera.position
    enemyTowards.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = true
    self.addChild(enemyTowards)

    print("spawning car right")
    timer.invalidate()
    resetTimer()

}


    func resetTimer() {

        self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5.0, target: self, selector: "spawningCars", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a physics body for the sprite before calling it:

```
enemyTowards.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: enemyTowardsTexture, size: enemyTowardsTexture.size())
```